# Update content of a dataframe's column when its name is declared inside brackets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Suppose that I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4,3)),columns=['A','B','C'])
df
     A    B    C
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Let's say that now I define a new variable `col` to access an specific columns of the dataframe. I can declare its value either inside or outside brackets:

```
col_1 = 'A'
print df[col_1]
col_2 = ['A']
print df[col_2]
```

However, when I try to update the content of the dataframe, only `df[col_1] = ...` works:

```
df[col_1] = np.ones(4)
print df
```

The second case is going to lead to an error:

```
df[col_2] = np.ones(4)
print df
```

The error is `ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (4,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,4)`.

I would like that both situation works since `col` is an parameter of a function.

#### Context

I am declaring a function where I would like to create a new dataframe with the same columns of the dataframe `X.columns` and zeros in all the elements, except the column `cols` (one or two columns) in which it should have the values of the array `values` (1D or 2D array). Here's how I declared:

```
def create_X_grid(X, values, cols):
    n_rows = len(values)
    n_columns = len(X.columns)
    X_grid = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((n_rows,n_columns)), columns=X.columns)
    X_grid[cols] = values
    return X_grid
```

It is possible that the user would put as input either `cols=['A']` or `cols='A'` so I would like to handle both situations.

Answer (score 0):

`df['A']` is a `pd.Series` with `shape` (4,) and `ndim` 1.

`df[['A']]` is a `pd.DataFrame` with `shape` (4,1) and `ndim` 2.

You can confirm this yourself by checking the `shape` and `ndmin` attributes of these objects.

The reason for the difference is that a dataframe typically has 2 axes: `axis=0` refers to rows, `axis=1` refers to columns. This differentiation is not required for a series.

Hence you can assign an array of dimension 1, e.g. `np.ones(4)`, to a series, but not to a dataframe.

A workaround, which you may not need to use, would be to change the shape of your `numpy` array:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4,3)),columns=['A','B','C'])

df[['A']] = np.ones(4)[:, None]
```

To handle both situations, I would advise to convert a list of a single element to a string before processing and use series assignment.

```
lst = ['A']

res = lst[0]  # alternatively next(iter(lst))
```

Comment: The workaround worked! I am going to check on my final code

Comment: hmm, I think it might get tricky when cols has two inputs like `cols=['A','C']`